# bloquear segunda aba de uma mesma sessão de usuário com JSF

Tags: java, jsf

Estou com um problema. 
Como faço para não permitir o acesso de duas abas em uma mesma sessão , utilizando JSF.

Tenho um sistema web onde cada usuário tem seu perfil. E o perfil é utilizado para gerar formulários personalizados. 
Apos a confirmação do perfil não permito mais a alteração do nome.

Acontece que estão abrindo duas ou mais abas simultâneas e ficam alterando os nomes imprimindo o mesmo documento com vários nomes.

Por esse motivo necessito bloquear a abertura de duas abas simultâneas de um mesmo usuário. Ou ao menos quando a segunda for aberta encerrar a sessão da primeira.

Comment: posta a imagem ou um exemplo ?

Comment: Ex. abrir o gmail em duas abas com o mesmo usuário.
Na minha aplicação necessito bloquear isso. Independente do navegador aberto ou se a aba é normal ou anonima.

Comment: Vc deve verificar se tem uma sessão ativa para o usuário.

Comment: vc quer controlar ambas não é?

Comment: na verdade quero somente uma aba ativa por usuário.